# How to verify if mobile phone number is correct?

Tags: python

I have a question is it possible to validate only mobile numbers in python-phonenumbers (https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) library in Python. I wrote code:

```
list = [...] #list of numbers to check
country = "XX"
is_valid = []
x = 0
while x < len(list):
    try:
        is_valid.append(phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phonenumbers.parse(list[x], country)))
        x = x + 1
    except:
        is_valid.append("False")
        x = x + 1
```

And it's working but mark landline phone as valid as well. Is there a way to exclude this kind?

Comment: https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/ed597f540500d32aa9cf65043ed88b45e0574c43/python/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.py#L1941